# Showing Non-Uniform Convergence of the Series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{k^2+x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I've been asked to show $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{k^2+x^2}$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ does not uniformly converge in $\mathbb{R}$. I do know and have already shown it plainly converges by the comparison test.

What I'm having with trouble is finding a value of $\epsilon$ that breaks the cauchy definition. We'd like to chose some $\epsilon$ so that $|\displaystyle\sum_{k=N+1}^{M}\frac{x^2}{k^2+x^2}|<\epsilon$ does not hold. Typically this involves chosing a value for $x$ smartly that forces the sum to just be some number, and then from there we can choose $\epsilon$ accordingly. These types of problems in general give me a hard time.

EDIT1: Having a hard time believing the proof given below, not sure if it holds for the chosen x.

EDIT2: Soo I think after meeting with some friends we were able to figure a much quicker way to do it than omnomnom's method below. A sequence of functions converges uniformly iff it is uniformly cauchy. Let

$S_{n}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{x^2}{k^{2}+x^{2}}$

and observe $|S_{n+1}-S_{n}|=\left|\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{(n+1)^2+x^2}\right|$. Now let $x=n+1$, so we have

$|S_{n+1}-S_{n}|=1/2$, Thus if we choose $\epsilon=1/4$ to begin with, we are done. I forgot that we could use the weaker version that takes advantage of consecutive terms of a sequence, and here it is quite helpful to do so. The appreciation I have in the below proof is mostly with the use of the Riemann sums. It's very neat and a useful thing to think about where applicable.

Comment: Note the terms $\textstyle{x^2\over k^2+x^2}$ do not converge uniformly to $0$ on $\Bbb R$ (fix a $k$ and take the limit as $x\rightarrow\infty$).

Comment: right, it goes to $1$..

Comment: So, in particular, the series is not uniformly Cauchy...

Comment: Okay, so I should be able to choose $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ and find there is no $M$ that satisfies the inequality? I need to be more rigorous in showing it, which is what I'm having a hard time with.

Comment: That would work; show the inequality does not hold for all $x\in\Bbb R$. Take any $M$, then show that there is an $x$ with $|f_M(x)|=|\sum_{n=M}^M f_M(x)|>1/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Cauchy definition is one way to go about this.  Another way is to define
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{k^2+x^2}
$$
And note that
$$
|f(x)-f_N(x)|=
\left|f(x)-\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{x^2}{k^2+x^2}\right|=
\left|\sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{k^2+x^2}\right|
$$
The key would then be to find a lower bound on this sum that depends on $x$ and $N$.  In particular, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{k^2+x^2}\right|
&= \sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{k^2+x^2}\\
&> \int_{N+1}^\infty \frac{x^2}{k^2+x^2}dk\\
&= x\int_{(N+1)/x}^\infty \frac{1}{1+u^2}du\\
&= x\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{N+1}{x}\right)\right)
\end{align}
$$
We find this inequality by noting that the left Riemann sum overestimates the integral of decreasing functions.

From there, we can show that for a given $N$, the difference between the $N^{th}$ partial sum and $f(x)$ can be made arbitrarily large by the selection of a sufficiently large $x$.

---

In particular, take $\epsilon=1$.  Consider any $N\in\mathbb N$.  We note that for $x>1$, we have
$$
\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{N+1}{x}\right) > 
\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(N+1\right) > 0
$$
Now, choose $x$ so that $x>1$ and $x>\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(N+1\right)\right)^{-1}$.  We then have
$$
\begin{align}
|f(x)-f_N(x)|&>x\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{N+1}{x}\right)\right)\\
&> x\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(N+1\right)\right)\\
&> \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(N+1\right)\right)^{-1}
\cdot
\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(N+1\right)\right)\\
&=1=\epsilon
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $f_n$ does not converge uniformly to $f$.

Comment: This is good, I'm just having trouble seeing how that riemann sum overestimates that integral.

Comment: Can you see why $$\frac{x^2}{x^2+k^2}>\int_k^{k+1}\frac{x^2}{x^2+k^2}dk?$$

Comment: The general equality for the above is just $$\int_a^b f(t)dt<M(b-a)$$ where $M$ is the maximum of $f$ on $[a,b]$.

Comment: Yes, I can see that, Since f is decreasing the max will always occur at k.

Comment: All right, now adding all of those integrals from $k$ to $k+1$ gives you the overall integral from $N+1$ to $\infty$

Comment: Hey Omnom, Are you sure that the arctan inequality is true? As x goes to infinity, it goes to 0. However, it does hold for $0<x<1$. So we can modify the proof.

Comment: I'm also unsure now that choosing x to be bigger than that expression will be valid anymore.

Comment: As $x$ goes to infinity, $\arctan(x)$ goes to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, not $0$. Again, our rule for "smartly" choosing $x$ is that $x>1$ and $x>\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(N+1\right)\right)^{-1}$.

Comment: Oh, I see, you mean that the inequality "goes to zero".  Yes, the inequality is true because $\arctan(x)$ is strictly increasing, so $f(x)>f(y)$ when $x>y$, and for all $x$, $x<\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$

Comment: The equality doesn't hold for $0<x<1$. For example, set $x=\frac12$ and $N=1$. We have $$\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{N+1}{x}\right)=  \frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(4\right)\approx 0.24 \\< 
\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(N+1\right) = \frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(2\right)\approx .46$$

Comment: I'm an idiot, I think I was looking at it late and was just ignoring the "arc" part of arctan. My bad, you got it.